# PrestaShop 1.6 logout when url is without index.php

Tags: php, session, authentication, prestashop-1.6

When customer is logged in and then he wants to go to Home Page by url i.e. www.prestashop.com/index.php then after page reload he is still logged. But when url is without index.php, just only www.prestashop.com, then page behaviorus like client logged out. No USERNAME in top, and he must log in again. I can't find reason.

---

EDIT

There's no problem with index.php or without in url, there's problem with https/http. Default SSL is enabled. When customer types **http** instead **https** then problem apear.

Comment: can you share a link to your site?

Comment: I can't because it's internal test serwer. But i supose i found reason, what is best way to check if conection is sił or not?